# How to retrieve the number of commits of a Git branch without downloading full commit history

Tags: git, commit

I need to obtain the commit count from a Git repository. How can I do this with a git command without downloading the entire commit history?

Comment: As it happened, in your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78147649/1) you were asking for a "method or tool"; I kindly suggest you always keep in mind that tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, and word your posts accordingly. If you were looking for a `git` command, you should have included this detail explicitly (beyond the title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git clone --bare --filter=tree:0   u://r/l
```

The main hosting services support filtering, if wherever's hosting your repo doesn't you'll need help from the administrators.

Answer (score -1):

Commit count for one revision (`HEAD`, `master`, or `commit hash`):

```
git rev-list --count <revision>
```

Commit count for all branches:

```
git rev-list --count --all
```

update: this is for local repositories

Comment: OP said "avoid downloading", the repo's not local. This won't work.

Comment: Exactly. I can download the last commit or need a remote repo command.

Comment: The point is, if you want to count commits *and* want to do this with a the command `git`, you cannot avoid downloading the whole commit history.

Comment: @j6t Are you sure about that or you just don't know how to do that? Because that's exactly what I was asking. 

I really don't wanna offend you but sometimes on Stackoverlow "I can't do it" is mistaken for "it can't be done".

Comment: @AlbertoSchiariti I'm pretty certain that it's not just "I can't do it", but "nobody can do it". That said, when we talk about "commit history" that is needed, then I mean it. That is, you need the *commits*, but you do not need the trees and blobs; therefore, you could use a filter to reduce download size like it was suggested.